# React Native/Typescript - Error Module '"react-native"' has no exported member 'Pressable'.ts(2305)

Tags: typescript, react-native

I cannot seem to remove this error message and don't know exactly where it comes from. Pressable is indeed a working component, but the thing that shouts at me doesn't understand that. What is it and how to fix it?

I tried updating react and react-native versions to latest, also tried upgrading typescript version to latest and still the error persists (the code runs fine though).

[image: This is what it looks like if I'm unclear]

Comment: Did you try to restart vscode/conputer?

Answer (score 13):

In my case I needed to update my @types/react-native dependency in `package.json` to `"@types/react-native": "^0.63.25",`

Comment: Thank you, that worked!! 

I'm really sorry for answering so late, it was the first time I ask anything on here and had completely forgotten about it. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

remove `@types/react-native` from `package.json` if exists.

then `yarn add --dev @types/react-native` or `npm install --save-dev @types/react-native` to install the latest version